# Rearrange the list of maps using Mule data weave

Tags: mule, dataweave

My input is a list of maps.

For example:

```
> [ { "key1" : "val1", "key2" : [item1,item2], "key3" : "obj1" }, {
> "key1" : "val2", "key2" : [item3,item4, item5], "key3" : "obj2" } ]
```

key2 value can be a list.

Desire output:

Output should be a list of objects with below structure.

```
[
{
"key1" : "val1", 
"key2" : "item1",
"key3" : "obj1"
},
{
"key1" : "val1", 
"key2" : "item2"
"key3" : "obj1"
},
{
"key1" : "val2", 
"key2" : "item3",
"key3" : "obj2"
},
{
"key1" : "val2", 
"key2" : "item4"
"key3" : "obj2"
},
{
"key1" : "val2", 
"key2" : "item5"
"key3" : "obj2"
}
]
```

How can i do this using data weave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use nested iteration on `key2`. Following code works fine

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
flatten (payload map ((parent,pIndex) -> (
    parent.key2 map {
        key1 : parent.key1,
        key2 : $,
        key3 : parent.key3
    }
)))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

%dw 1.0
%output application/json

### %var index = 1

payload map ((payload01,indexOfPayload01) -> {
         key1 : payload01.key1,
         key2 :payload01[index].key2,
         key3 : payload01.key3
       })

Answer (score 0):

The input you provided may seem to have some issue. [ 
{ 
"key1" : "val1", 
"key2" : ["item1","item2"], 
"key3" : "obj1" 
},
{
"key1" : "val2", 
"key2" : ["item3","item4","item5"],
"key3" : "obj2" 
} 
] 
This should be the correct request.

Answer (score -1):

Since key2 is an arrray you should loop through this with map operator and form the json final object as you would like it to be